# Automate running SQL filetype scripts when opening a PHP file

Tags: autocmd, filetype

When I open a PHP file in Vim I want Vim to provide SQL assistance as well as all the PHP assistance.
From [`:h sql-completion-filetypes`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/ft_sql.txt.html#sql-completion-filetypes):

> This can be enabled easily with the following steps (assuming a Perl
>   file):
>
> ```
> 1.  :e test.pl  
> 2.  :set filetype=sql  
> 3.  :set ft=perl
> ```

I would like to automate this:
So far I have tried

Appending the following commands to `~/.vim/after/ftplugins/php.vim`

```
:set filetype=sql  
:set ft=php
```

This throws errors like

```
Error detected while processing FileType Auto commands for "*":       
E218: autocommand nesting too deep
```

Which I'm assuming is happening because when whenever the `set ft=php` command is run - it then re-triggers the `~/.vim/after/ftplugins/php.vim` script which then re-triggers the `set ft=php` statement.
Is it possible to automate running these commands `:set filetype=sql`, `:set ft=php` when opening a php file?

Comment: `setf sql.php` to set multiple filetypes on a file. To automate this: `autocmd FileType php setf sql.php`

Comment: thanks, its a good idea, but unfortunately it doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On my Vim (7.4.944), the SQL filetype plugin performs [the following check](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/ftplugin/sql.vim#L101):

```
if !exists("*SQL_SetType")
    " NOTE: You cannot use function! since this file can be
    " sourced from within this function.  That will result in
    " an error reported by Vim.
```

That seems to be a good way to load `sql.vim` once. So, in my `~/.vim/ftplugin/php.vim`, I added:

```
if !exists("*SQL_SetType")
    set ft=sql
    set ft=php
endif
```

I don't use SQL in PHP, but AFAICT, the SQL settings were loaded.

Comment: thanks muru, it works! so basically this code snippet says: if  `SQL_SetType` hasn't been set that means `sql.vim` hasn't run - so run the  `set ft=sql set ft=php` commands - the `set ft=php` will cause your snippet to re-run - but your if condition will protect against the recursion (kind of like putting up shields to protect against disruptor fire - I guess...)

Comment: @the_velour_fog yep. If you're familiar with C, it's like an [include guard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard). Note also that I used `~/.vim/ftplugin`, and not `after/ftplugin`, since I want this to run as early as possible, so that a minimum of PHP-related code is called twice.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I was wondering why you did that. Yes I am familiar with the programming pattern of include guards, but annoyingly I don't know vimscript, so I couldn't write something like your code snippet!

Comment: @the_velour_fog if it helps, I didn't write it. I just lifted it from `sql.vim`. :P